# Can I make an autoclicker, only using the standard library?

Tags: python, automation

I am new-ish to python, so bear with me here.

I would like to make an autoclicker that would work on any device with IDLE, if I copy/paste the code, whether or not it has extra libraries (modules?) tacked on.
If it helps, this is for a 2014 MacBook Air.

Ideally, it would look something like this:

```
if key is pressed:
    active = True

while active is True:
    (simulate mouse click)
```

I've seen a similar question, but everyone suggested PyAutoGUI, which is not in the standard library.

I'm not sure whether it's possible to do this, however.

It's pretty simple, except I have no idea how to actually do it.

Comment: Does it have to be Python? If you're prevented from using external libraries you're probably SOL if you want to stick with pure Python. It looks like people are typically using AppleScript to do what you want; and it appears you can call AppleScript code with Python: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28058546/using-python-in-place-of-applescript

Comment: I'm kind of confused - why not just install pyautogui? It takes little time or effort

Comment: Rebecca- because I am a 13 year old child whose parents aren't willing to download pyautogui

Comment: @AidanTung if you want to be sneaky you can run `pip install pyautogui` from a command line and it doesn't require any "downloads"

Comment: Yeah, You can do window + r and type `cmd` and run `pip install pyautogui`

Comment: @mazore, I have tried, but it does not work. I do not know if it has something to do with my laptop being a Mac, or something else (maybe pip was not installed with python, or was installed wrong), but it returns `Syntaxerror: invalid syntax`

Comment: @AidanTung You ran it in the python console (usually starts with `>>>`), which is used for running python commands like `print('Hello')`. If you use the terminal application (a "command line interface") then that might work.

Comment: @mazore This time, there was a little window that appeared at the top of the idle window, saying "invalid syntax" with an "ok" button

Answer (score 1):

```py
import time

from ctypes import windll
time.sleep(3)
for _ in range(20000):
  windll.user32.mouse_event(6, 0, 0, 0, 0) # max clicks per second: (50 - 3057)
# it's the simplest calculator for speed 

from pyautogui import click
time.sleep(3)
click(clicks=20000,_pause=False) # clicks per second: (150 - 3350)
# it's also fast calculator but with pyautogui

# it's an unexpected result for me and most likely I accidentally managed to click more using pyautogui
# Note: windll supported by Windows and I don't recommend you try this in another platform
```

Comment: Whilst the code is useful, it is important to add context and information outside of the code snippet to make it more meaningful.