# Using subprocess to perform menu options in a unix executable

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm using subprocess to open a unix executable, myapp, and pass an argument consisting of a file in .edf format, named sample.edf:

```
app=subprocess.Popen('/users/fishbacp/Desktop/myapp.app/Contents/MacOS/myapp 
'+'/users/fishbacp/Desktop/sample.edf', shell=True)
```

This successfully launches the app and loads sample.edf. Various signal processing operations can be performed on sample.edf using a menu of options. At the end, I wish to perform one such menu option consisting of

Tools->Export as EDF ->Export.

Is there a means of modifying my subprocess command or introducing a new subprocess to accomplish this within my python script?

Using Python 3.7 and Mac OSX 10.15.4

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but `shell=True` is basically always a bad idea. You avoid serious security issues if you don't use it, and pass your application name and your argument as two separate list entries.

Comment: _Related_ to your question, `subprocess` has no concept of "menus", or GUIs at all. If you want to script GUI operations, you'll need to use a library for the purpose, and the Python standard library doesn't ship with anything of that sort out-of-the-box.

Comment: If `myapp` is truly your own application, perhaps you might build it a dedicated CLI entrypoint, so it can have components invoked without any GUI interaction needed at all?

Comment: See [Using Python in place of AppleScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28058546/using-python-in-place-of-applescript) -- though the answer boils down to "you can't".